# P is closed under power of integer

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, polynomial-time

I'm new in this area of complexity and I'm trying to get into it by understanding basic proofs.

I want to prove that if $L\in P$, so $L^k\in P$, where $k$ is non-negative integer.

How to prove it in the "official" way?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? What do you mean by "official"?

Comment: You previously asked [the same question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51149/755), and it was put on hold.  Then you deleted it and asked the same question a second time.  in the future, rather than re-asking a second time, it would be better to edit the original question to address the feedback.  For reference, the prior feedback included: "What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual problems but just answering homework-style questions for you is unlikely to help you understand.", and I think that still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proof for NP. You generalize it to P.

Let $L$ be a language in NP. Thus there is a polytime non-deterministic Turing machine $T$ that accepts $x$ iff $x \in L$. Using $T$, we can construct a non-deterministic Turing machine that accepts $L^k$. On input $x$, the machine first guesses (non-deterministically) a partition $x=x_1\ldots x_k$, and then verifies that $x_1,\ldots,x_k \in L$ using $T$. It's not hard to check that this machine also runs in polynomial time.

When generalizing the argument to P we have to implement the partition guessing in a deterministic way – details left to you.